# Is it possible/necessary to change the garbage-collection intervals in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I know that the `garbage-collection` is used to get rid of the orphaned objects (the ones that loses their references) but is it possible to set custom intervals for `garbage-collecting` in `Java`?

Comment: For most implementations, including Oracle’s HotSpot JVM, the garbage collector doesn’t run in fixed intervals, but depending on the memory consumption of your application. Simply said, as long as there is enough memory, it doesn’t run at all. There are plenty of options, first to pick particular algorithms, then, algorithm specific options, like allocation thresholds to trigger collections. But before digging into them, you should think about which actual problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not advisable for an application to tell the GC to run.  It is better to leave it to the JVM to make the decision.

Why?

Because the JVM knows best.  The JVM has access to information that allows it to run the JVM at the best time, to optimize either for high throughput or low pause times.  It can monitor the size of the various heap "spaces", and estimate the best time to initiate a collection, and what kind of collection to initiate.  The decision making is complicated.

By contrast, if an application calls `System.gc()` on a fixed time interval, it may run when it doesn't need to, using CPU cycles unnecessarily.  Indeed, if you run the GC when there is no garbage, it spend a lot of time *scanning* all of the live objects ... and then not achieve anything.

The other thing to note that if `System.gc()` is not ignored, a common behavior is to run a full garbage collection.  Depending on your JVM's GC options, this may cause all application threads to be frozen.  If the heap is large, the "GC pauses" for full collections can be significant.

---

Another answer suggests using the `sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval` property.  This is designed to deal with the collection of remote references in an RMI application.  It *may* work in other contexts, but it is inadvisable for the reasons stated above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed input @Stephen C, it really helped. I was simply curious about GC and how it worked, and it's much clearer now. Tho I don't understand why I got down-votes for this question. Many people took the time to explain which clearly shows it was worth addressing. Don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` or `System.gc()` you can suggest JVM for garbage collection but you cannot set intervals or call it in any way

> [public static void gc​()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--)
>
> Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a garbage collection is, that the developer does not need to worry about the memory management whatsoever (as always there might be exceptions, but these are rare)

As pointed out you can only suggest the JVM to trigger the GC from your java code.

If you have problems with your GC interval, maybe you can instead set some parameters to your JVM?
Maybe you can use the parameter:

```
gcInterval(ms) = max interval between GC
```

But I have never used it myself, so no experience on this one.

Comment: If you are talking about the `sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval` property, that is primarily for use in RMI application to deal with remote references.  It should not be used normally.